# How to use a multiple values in where in statement of SQL?

Tags: php, sql, oracle

Let say I have a table containing the following values:

```
ID | role | group | name
--------------------------
1  | A    | A     | John
2  | B    | A     | Paul
3  | C    | A     | Mary
4  | A    | B     | Peter
5  | B    | B     | Mark
6  | C    | B     | May
7  | A    | C     | Sam
8  | B    | C     | Samson
9  | C    | C     | Naomi
```

Then, let say I want user from group B with role A and user from group C with role C, I can write a SQL like the following:

```
select * from my_table 
where (role = 'A' and group = 'B') 
   or (role = 'C' and group = 'C')
```

This works, but the problem is that in real case, these sets is to be set by user and there will be many of them. Usually, if that is only single value query, I can do:

```
select * from my_table where id in (:id_list)
```

Then I can pass an array of IDs into the statement directly. Is there a way I can use where in in multiple values as a set?

P.S. I am using PHP with oracle database, but I think that should not matter much as I am asking for a SQL statement.

Comment: How you do this depends on the database you are using and the application you are using to access it.  Please tag appropriately.

Comment: Added.... although I wonder if that really matters that much.

Comment: Regarding, `but I think that should not matter much as I am asking for a SQL statement.`, of course it matters.  You realize the S in SQL does not stand for Standard, right?

Comment: What is wrong with your current query and what would change which would make it not be workable?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . The OP is asking how to pass in lots of pairs in a simple way from PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know php, but your SQL query is equivalent to this, if it helps you in some way. `GROUP` is a sql keyword, I changed it to grp

```
SELECT * 
FROM   my_table 
WHERE  ( role, grp ) IN ( ( 'A', 'B' ), ( 'C', 'C' ) );
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e231d/6)